# Libgdx camera rotate around on a center point with EulerAngles

Tags: android, libgdx

Here is my code:

```
private Quaternion getRotatedQuaternion(float pitch, float yaw, float roll) {
    tempQuat.setEulerAngles(pitch, yaw, roll);
    rotationQuat.mulLeft(tempQuat);

    return rotationQuat;
}
```

and

```
            camera.view.setToLookAt(tempPos, tempLookat, Axis.UP);

            Quaternion rotQuat = getRotatedQuaternion(gestureListener.getXAngle(), gestureListener.getYAngle(), 0);
            camera.view.rotate(rotQuat);
            camera.combined.set(camera.projection);

            Matrix4.mul(camera.combined.val, camera.view.val);
```

This is a camera rotation in the center, on 0,0,0. Gimbal lock probleme solved by this way. But how can I add a new center point to it?

Basically I want to rotate the camera around my object, not 0,0,0

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up with two matrox rotation and a vector to use as an arcball rotation

Comment: Could you kindly expand this so others can understand how you solved your problem?

Comment: Please share the solution, else this should be considered against the rules of the community

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert from Polar Coordinates (r,θ) to Cartesian Coordinates (x,y) 
the formula is the following:

x = r × cos( θ )

y = r × sin( θ )

The angle is relative to your object central point (0º to 360º), the radius is the distance from your object to your camera.

Here's a simple method that does that for you:

```
public static Vector3 returnPosArroundObj(Vector3 posObject, Float angleDegrees, Float radius, Float height) {
    Float angleRadians = angleDegrees * MathUtils.degreesToRadians;
    Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    position.set(radius * MathUtils.sin(angleRadians), height, radius * MathUtils.cos(angleRadians));
    position.add(posObject); //add the position so it would be arround object
    return position;
}
```

Comment: I need to do this rotation without gimbal lock. Also I have 2 angles. AngleX and AngleY. By the way my old code looks like the same as this

Comment: so you just use math, x = r sin θ cos φ,
y = r sin θ sin φ,
z = r cos θ

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could do that is to first, move the camera to the object's position, rotate, and move the camera back to the original spot.

So something like:

```
Camera.setposition(object.pos)
Camera.rotate()
Camera.setposition(original-camera-pos)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gimbal lock"?